# How to find the drive letter of a newly inserted USB drive using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to accomplish this:

When I insert a USB drive in Windows (Win7 and Win8), I want a script to be started (Powershell or batch command) automatically.  The machine has autoplay disabled.

I setup a scheduled task with event id 2010 in DriveFrameworks-UserMode as trigger.  The scheduled task works.  However, I am having difficulties finding the drive letter of the newly inserted USB drive.

I found a few solutions on the Internet, but they didn't fit my requirements.  The solutions either check for all drive letters (A to Z), or check for USB drive.  I would like to correlate the drive letter that is associated with the event in the DriveFrameworks-UserMode trigger.

This post ([How do i get the drive letter of a USB Drive in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634396/how-do-i-get-the-drive-letter-of-a-usb-drive-in-powershell)) gave me some hints and I checked classes win32_logicaldisk, win32_diskdrive, and win32_pnpentity, but I couldn't find a clue matching them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any code to review?

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"}
$letters = $diskdrive | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_. deviceid} 

$drive = gwmi win32_volume | ? {$letters -contains ($_.name -replace "\\")}
$drive.DriveLetter
```

PS. There is a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068112/assigning-fixed-drive-letters-to-usb-devices-on-windows-server-2012/27069803?noredirect=1#comment42665380_27069803)

Comment: Thank you Micky.  This is similar to the solution I posted in my original question.  However, I am looking for more than that.  My problem is, assume I already have a USB drive connected.  When I insert a second USB drive, I need to find out the drive letter of the second USB drive.  I was trying to match the deviceID or whatever using from wmi classes with the information found in the eventid 2010.  However I failed.  Thanks